# Run a Custom ROM on an AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, rom

Does anyone know if this it is possible to run a Custom ROM on a AVD?
ANd how can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you build a custom rom by yourself, after you've built a custom rom you can launch it with the command `emulator`. But to do this you need at first to build your rom for emulator (usually, `full-generic` lunch option). If not you can just copy necessary images and also run them using `emulator` command. For instance, I usually copy .sh script in the folder with Android sources and run this script:

```
out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -sysdir out/target/product/generic/ -system out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/userdata.img -kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu -sdcard sdcard.img -skindir sdk/emulator/skins -skin WVGA800 -scale 0.7 -memory 512 -wipe-data -partition-size 200
```

Comment: Sry, i dont have running a linux

Comment: If you have this rom (build for emulator) you can just find other images that are required for running emulator (userdata.img and so on) (you download them with the SDK), copy them into the folder and run emulator command (emulator tool is also a part of SDK) and specify parameters (set the path to your folder with images).

Comment: You provided a custom script for your setup. Could you explain the `-kernel` option (say I want to run a kernel in a boot.img image)?