# How to do I test my custom android ROM in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, rom

I have made a custom android ROM that I would like to test but I don't have and android device so I was thinking I could test it in the emulator.
Is that possible ?
if yes how can I do it ?

thank you for you help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a Custom ROM on an AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744342/run-a-custom-rom-on-an-avd)